# The use of the word "copy" instead of "text"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the word **copy** instead of the word **text** in some contexts?

For example, the titles of two tasks were as follows:

> Update log out copy in the profile menu

and

> Copy for notifications

Which respectively means `Update the text of the logout button` and `List of texts for notifications`

For me, the use of the word **copy** here seems a bit strange and somewhat incorrect, however, I was not able to find any source on the use of **copy** to mean **text**.

---

Edit:
I was referred by my colleague to this [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/copy), specifically to the *"written text that is to be printed, or text that is intended to help with the sale of a product"* section. However, I don't personally believe this is the same use case.

Comment: The 2 examples you gave don't make sense to me at all. This suddenly makes me double my English skill...

Comment: One definition of _copy_ is _matter to be printed_. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/copy

Comment: @KateBunting Just found the same link from a previous argument with my college.
But does it make sense to use the same meaning in the context of a text of a button? In the link provided, it refers specifically to a "text to be printed"

Comment: *Copy* is a common term for text in the context of news media and advertising, but I wouldn't use it to describe the label on a button. In the context of editing a web page or application menu it would be confused with the clipboard copy function.

Comment: Context needed!

Comment: Did you scroll down to "copy _noun_ (TEXT)"?

Comment: @CJDennis Yes I actually did, but again the example referred to a specific case and not a generic meaning, so I was not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to use *copy* to mean *text* in certain contexts, such as advertising and in print media.

Your colleague cited Cambridge:

> text that is to be printed, or text that is used to sell a product:
>   *She writes advertising copy.*

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/copy)

Consider your first example.

> ? Update log out copy in the profile menu

The *text* (not *copy*) will appear on a computer screen, not, say, for a printed newspaper or magazine. So in this context, the words are not interchangeable.

If you were working for an advertising firm or a magazine or a newspaper, someone might say:

> Submit the *copy* / *text* for the coronavirus outbreak by noon, or you're fired.

Either would work.

But for a non-print medium, someone would say:

> Submit the *text* for the coronavirus outbreak by noon.

Comment: "Copy" is also used to describe the text used by the reporter or anchor person in television and radio news stories.

Comment: Agreed, and a copyeditor could edit in many media, extending the notion of printed news to TV or online text.

Comment: It's often said that text is printed to screen. Why wouldn't _copy_ cover this meaning?

Comment: It would be an extension of an extension to use copy in this context, @CJDennis. You would be extending the text on screen to be "printed."  Then the "print" of the screen is extended to an advertisement or a newspaper column. You could do the stretch, but I think the OP was correcting in fearing that "the word *copy* here seems a bit strange."

Comment: @rajah9 The first time I encountered _copy_ as in _advertising copy_ it sounded strange to me. Now that I'm used to it, it doesn't sound strange as in "prepared text containing a message for customers".

Answer (score -1):

yes, it is correct. otherwise, you wouldn't have a term "[microcopy](https://uxdesign.cc/my-favourite-microcopy-cc5560f1cdfd?gi=a857c2e36e45)"